# matching div heights with jQuery

Tags: jquery, height, match

trying to match div heights using jQuery, and it seems I can only get it to match the smallest height, but I want it to match the tallest column. from what I can tell the code should find tallest column? so I am very confused, here is what I am using

```
function matchColHeights(col1, col2) {
    var col1Height = $(col1).height();
    var col2Height = $(col2).height();
    if (col1Height < col2Height) {
        $(col1).height(col2Height);
    } else {
        $(col2).height(col1Height);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    matchColHeights('#leftPanel', '#rightPanel');
});
```

trying to do it here: http://www.tigerstudiodesign.com/blog/

Comment: Linking to your site is all well and good, but _which bits_ are you trying to match heights?

Comment: leftPanel and rightPanel, like the code states.

Comment: `leftPanel` and `rightPanel` could be _anything_. Also, you don't tell us what to look for when they're not the same height. To me, the page design works fine in FF. Can you provide correct/incorrect screenshots or a diagram or something?

Comment: how can it be anything? they are in the layout, hah. very specific ID's. I am very confused. anyway, here is a diagram just in case. http://localhostr.com/files/IijP6y2/Screen+Shot+2011-12-21+at+3.37.16+PM+copy.jpg

Comment: Is there anything that gets loaded after the page is `ready`? Specifically into the right column? It appears that when this code is initially running the right column is shorter than the left. If you check the true height value after the everything has run it is taller than the left column. Your JS function works fine, there is something up with that right column.

Comment: It may be something with Wordpress? Check this out, this is all of your files in a fiddle (with extra bg colors for clarity): http://jsfiddle.net/nXFJB/1/

Comment: this is actually all just HTML right now, no wordpress implemented just yet. There is nothing that is loaded after page is ready other than matchColHeights. without the JS you can see the right is taller and has a height. if you turn JS off, you can see this. very confused.

Comment: i believe you are right, now that I look at it, it is getting the height way too early. it doesn't give the images time to load. is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

This should be able to set more than one column to maxheight. Just specify the selectors just like you would if you wanted to select all your elements with jQuery.

```
function matchColHeights(selector){
    var maxHeight=0;
    $(selector).each(function(){
        var height = $(this).height();
        if (height > maxHeight){
            maxHeight = height;
        }
    });
    $(selector).height(maxHeight);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    matchColHeights('#leftPanel, #rightPanel, #middlePanel');
});
```

Comment: this seems to be working now at least appending a height, but I need it to grab the max height, this grabs the min height.

Answer (score 2):

**one line alternative**

```
$(".column").height(Math.max($(col1).height(), $(col2).height()));
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/dESx6/

It seems to work fine for me?

**javascript**

```
function matchColHeights(col1, col2) {
    var col1Height = $(col1).height();
    console.log(col1Height);
    var col2Height = $(col2).height();
    console.log(col2Height);
    if (col1Height < col2Height) {
        $(col1).height(col2Height);
    } else {
        $(col2).height(col1Height);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    matchColHeights('#leftPanel', '#rightPanel');
});
```

**css**

```
.column {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="column" id="leftPanel">Lorem ipsum...</div>
<div class="column" id="rightPanel"></div>
```

Comment: div's autogrow depending on their content

Comment: I know, that is the problem. heh :/

Comment: they autogrow, so they have a height. now with the script you get the shorter one to match the taller one, see the fiddle

Comment: oh, right. maybe I wasn't being specific, I need to match the taller height as it auto grows. I thought that's what code does? it shouldn't be other way around according to the code, unless I am missing something. I see that it works in the test envoirnment, but for some reason on my site it's not working? :/ maybe a div isn't clearing correctly or something? I'm not sure. cant seem to find the problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6050/discussion-between-c4urself-and-lukasz)

Comment: height is being set by JS, so there is no height on it, if you turn of JS with dev tools you should be able to see it as is without JS.

Answer (score 0):

When I load your site in Chrome, #leftPanel has a height of 1155px and #rightPanel has a height of 1037px. The height of #rightPanel is then set, by your matchColHeights method, to 1155px.

*However*, if I allow the page to load, then use the Chrome Developer Tools console to remove the style attribute that sets an explicit height on #rightPanel, its height becomes 1473px. So, your code is correctly setting the shorter of the two columns to the height of the taller at the time the code runs. But subsequent formatting of the page would have made the other column taller.

Answer (score 0):

The best tut on this subject could be found here:

http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/